# "If it was raining"

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If it was raining, we **stayed** at home.

I think "we would be staying at home" is fine, but my teacher said it was "stayed" and "if" referred to "when"? Which is true?

Comment: The statement as stands is a valid and grammatical response to a question like **Q**: "What did your family do on April 12th, which according to the weather report was very rainy?" **A**: "If it was raining, we stayed at home."

Answer (score 2):

If it was raining, we stayed at home.

The sentence is grammatical.

It's conditional type 2 that expresses an imaginary situation that's not likely to happen in the present or future.

The if-clause can be in the past simple or continuous. You usually use would in the main clause, but it can also be in the simple past.

Comment: so if I use "would stay", it is fine, isn't it?

Comment: @Mr.Finger, Yes, it's fine.